# If space is available add element to html

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am displaying a list of 15 images. Depending on the width of the images (yes the images width varies) and the width of the screen size, there may be a different amount of images on each row.

For example, there is a case that I have 3 rows of 4 images and 1 row of 3 images.  Now on the last row, there is an empty space.  How can I add some element or text to the empty space on the last row and only if it is empty? So if I have 3 rows of 15 images, I shouldn't see my added element.

This is how my html looks:

```
<div class="view-content">
  <div class="views-row views-row-1"><a href="#"><img src="http://www.example.com/image.jpg /><a/></div>
  <div class="views-row views-row-2"><a href="#"><img src="http://www.example.com/image.jpg /><a/></div>
  <div class="views-row views-row-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://www.example.com/image.jpg /><a/></div>
  <div class="views-row views-row-4"><a href="#"><img src="http://www.example.com/image.jpg /><a/></div>
  <div class="views-row views-row-5"><a href="#"><img src="http://www.example.com/image.jpg /><a/></div>
  <div class="views-row views-row-6"><a href="#"><img src="http://www.example.com/image.jpg /><a/></div>
  <div class="views-row views-row-7"><a href="#"><img src="http://www.example.com/image.jpg /><a/></div>
  <div class="views-row views-row-8"><a href="#"><img src="http://www.example.com/image.jpg /><a/></div>
  <div class="views-row views-row-9"><a href="#"><img src="http://www.example.com/image.jpg /><a/></div>
  <div class="views-row views-row-10"><a href="#"><img src="http://www.example.com/image.jpg /><a/></div>
  <div class="views-row views-row-11"><a href="#"><img src="http://www.example.com/image.jpg /><a/></div>
  <div class="views-row views-row-12"><a href="#"><img src="http://www.example.com/image.jpg /><a/></div>
  <div class="views-row views-row-13"><a href="#"><img src="http://www.example.com/image.jpg /><a/></div>
  <div class="views-row views-row-14"><a href="#"><img src="http://www.example.com/image.jpg /><a/></div>
  <div class="views-row views-row-15"><a href="#"><img src="http://www.example.com/image.jpg /><a/></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is the img height or width absolute?

Comment: @Jonasw No it is not.

Comment: But the row must have an absolute height

Comment: Or is the height of the row = the height of the largest image?

Comment: @Jonasw I guess there is a height and width for the image but it may change based on the screen size. For example on a mobile screen we may want to display 2 images on one row but on desktop we may want to display 4 or 5.

Comment: So the images all have the same format?

Comment: If they all have different format, theres no easy solution. Look for gallery systems out there or try to write it yourself. This will take a few hundred lines. Thats to much for SO, its more a project on GitHub ...

Comment: For an easy solution, you need to at least provide different row heights that are applied onto the images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure this out by looking at the last item and figuring out how much space is to the right side of the screen. If there is enough room I add my element.

```
var item = '.views-row-15';
var element = $(item);

// Get the screen size.
var screen_size = $(window).width();

// Calculate the amount of empty space by looking at the space between the
// end of the window and the element.
var amount_of_empty_space = screen_size - (element.offset().left + element.width());

// If past this amount add the button.
if (amount_of_empty_space > 240) {
  var button = '';
  button += '<div class="views-row-more">';
  button += '  <div class="more-styles-button--text">See  More</div>';
  button += '</div>';

  $(button).insertAfter(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onresize=a;
window.onload=a;
function a(){
imgs=document.getElementsByTagName("img");
totalwidth=0;
rows=1;
imgs.forEach(function(img){
//ad img to row
totalwidth+=img.width;
if(totalwidth>window.innerWidth){
//row is full;
totalwidth=img.width;
//add img to new row
rows++;
//new row
}
}
height=rows*300;
//assuming img.height is 300px

if(height<window.innerHeight){
//oh we have space
space=window.innerHeight-height;
//add something
document.createElement(...);
//do it yourself
}
}
```

This only works if the row has an absolute height:

```
img{height:300px;}
```